# Determine when a object is different to the next in a mutable array and return the index where the object is different

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

The code:

```
+(void) getRowSeperationIndexOfData{


DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];

sharedManager.linesCount = 1;

NSUInteger totalItemsInLINEreading = [sharedManager.LINEreading count]-1;

NSArray *LINEreadingCopy = [sharedManager.LINEreading copy];

if(sharedManager.LINEreading.count > 1 ){

    [sharedManager.uniqueLineNumber addObject:@"1"];

    //Count through the array LINEreadingCopy and return profileStartIndexes integer (where the value in the array is different), this can now be used to set the rows of the table that will display the profiles
    for (int i = 0; i < totalItemsInLINEreading; i +=1) {

        if ([LINEreadingCopy objectAtIndex:i] != [LINEreadingCopy objectAtIndex:i+1]){

            sharedManager.linesCount += 1;

            //populate the array uniqueLineNumber with the different line numbers
            [sharedManager.uniqueLineNumber addObject:[LINEreadingCopy objectAtIndex:i+1]];

            //i would be the index that needs to be added to a new array
            [sharedManager.profileStartIndexes addObject:@(i)];
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",sharedManager.LINEreading);
// NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)sharedManager.linesCount);
NSLog(@"%@",sharedManager.profileStartIndexes);
//NSLog(@"%@",sharedManager.uniqueLineNumber);
}
```

The output: 
Note that the first output is the actual array that I am counting through to determine where the objects are different and to give me the index in the array. It does not want to work for some reason, I think the array objects are stored as numbers but I don't know how to change my function to accommodate number formatting.

```
  2016-05-24 13:49:44.590 GeoData Grapher[3920:180503] (
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
2,
2,
2,
2,
3,
3,
3
  )
  2016-05-24 13:49:44.591 GeoData Grapher[3920:180503] (
0,
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10,
11,
12,
13,
14,
15,
16,
17,
18,
19,
20,
21,
22,
23,
24,
25
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a correct answer, you really need to know exactly how `sharedManager.LINEreading` values are stored, but....

Assuming it's some form of `NSNumber` is reasonable.  The most likely fix then would be to compare `int` values.

```
if ([[LINEreadingCopy objectAtIndex:i] intValue] != [[LINEreadingCopy objectAtIndex:i+1] intValue]) {
```

When you find out how the values are **really** stored, you may want to change to `integerValue`, or `longValue`, or `shortValue`, or whatever matches.